# Angular Universal inside docker: Cannot read property 'getOptionsDiagnostics' of undefined

Tags: angular, docker, webpack, angular-universal

I have Angular 5.2 app with universal rendering enabled (mostly implemented according to [this article](https://medium.com/@evertonrobertoauler/angular-5-universal-with-transfer-state-using-angular-cli-19fe1e1d352c)). Everything works on my local environment, but when I try to build the app in docker, it fails with this error:

```
$ node --max-old-space-size=4096 ./node_modules/.bin/webpack -p
/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:91633
       return program.getOptionsDiagnostics(cancellationToken).concat(program.getGlobalDiagnostics(cancellationToken));
                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'getOptionsDiagnostics' of undefined
    at Object.getCompilerOptionsDiagnostics (/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:91633:28)
    at provideCompilerOptionDiagnosticErrorsToWebpack (/app/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/after-compile.js:39:29)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/after-compile.js:17:9)
    at next (/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:204:14)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/CachePlugin.js:78:5)
    ...
```

I tried to build with `node:carbon` image and with `ubuntu:16.04` + installed `node` via `apt`, same error in both images.

This error is caused in last stage of build, where I use webpack to build the server app (`$ node --max-old-space-size=4096 ./node_modules/.bin/webpack -p`).

I use webpack 3.11, with this config:

```
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    server: './src/server.ts',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    alias: {
      'main.server': path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'server', 'main.bundle.js'),
    },
  },
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals({
    whitelist: [
      /^@ng-bootstrap\/ng-bootstrap/,
      /ngx-translate-messageformat-compiler/,
    ],
  })],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution myself, in webpack config I enabled `transpileOnly` option of `ts-loader` and this error magically disappeared. In this case the code is already type checked so no real need to that anyway.

```
{ test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader', options: { transpileOnly: true } },
```